# Summarizing the Distributional Derivative of a Piecewise Smooth Function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

> Suppose $f\in C^1$. Define
>
> $$g(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> f'(x)  & \text{if $x\ne x_0$} \\
> 0 & \text{if $x=x_0$}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> (a) If $f$ is continuous at $x=x_0$, show that $f'=g$ in the sense of distributions
>
> (b) If $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $x_0$ where
>
> $$a=\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^-} f(x)$$ $$b=\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^+} f(x)$$
>
> show that $f'=g+(b-a)\delta_{x_0}$ in the sense of distributions

I'm trying to proceed using definitions of distributional derivatives, continuity, and the delta function, but I can barely make sense of what the question is suggesting.

Any help is greatly appreciated!